# jQuery Validation - same messages displays many times when clicking on submit button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have implement the jQuery Validation plugin on my website. When I click on Submit Button without filling required text box, then required field message displays many times.

Like I am clicking on Submit button three times, then message displays three times. It should only display only one time.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#frm").validate(
  {
    rules : {
      cat_name : {
        required: true
      },
      cat_description : {
        required : true
      }
    },
    messages : {
      cat_name : {
        required:"<br />Please enter category name"
      },
      cat_description : {
        required:"<br /> Please enter category description"
      }
    }
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="99%" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="right">
    <form method="post" action="save_livefeed_categories.php" class="cmxform" id="frm" name="frm">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center" class="venueError" id="venueError"></div></td>
            </tr>
                <input type="hidden" value="0" id="update" name="update">
                <input type="hidden" value="" id="cat_id" name="cat_id">
            <tr>
                <td height="10" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="22%" height="25" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Category Name :</strong></td>
                <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" value="" id="cat_name" name="cat_name"></td>         
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="22%" height="25" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Category Description :</strong></td>
                <td width="50%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><textarea cols="35" rows="8" id="cat_description" name="cat_description"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right"></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left">
                    <input type="image" name="Save" id="Save" src="images/bt_save.gif">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="image" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="javascript:window.location.replace('livefeed_categories.php'); return false;" src="images/bt_cancel.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Output**
[image: jQuery Error]

Comment: try _errorPlacement: function (error, element) { error.insertAfter(element);
}_

Comment: @A.V thanks for reply can you please tell me where i have to put this function in my code?

Comment: Add after closing braces for _messages_... Also put 'comma'

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Something else must be interfering with the validate script: http://jsfiddle.net/uEWCK/

Comment: @leepowers you are right because the same code is working in other forms but here it is not working !!!

Comment: same code is working in IE but not working in Mozzila and chrome

Comment: As already stated by others, the code you posted is valid and should not behave like that.  It's now up to you to provide additional code, a demo or link that shows us how to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happened because i have added `<form>` tag inside the `<table>` tag. now its working fine.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: And we could have helped you if you had just posted the HTML as requested.